# Что использовать, что бы метод работал пока не пройдет определенное время?

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы метод работал определенное время, например выводил в textarea слово 5 секунд, что для этого можно использовать?

Comment: Асинхронщину, setTimeout/setInterval

Comment: @andreymal, есть еще что-нибудь другое кроме этого?

Comment: Вряд ли . . . .

Comment: _"есть еще что-нибудь другое кроме этого?"_ - а зачем что-то другое? При том что `setTimeout()` идеально подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let output = document.getElementById('output'),
    interval = setInterval(() => { output.textContent += 'слово '; }, 1000);
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(interval); }, 5000);
```

```html
<textarea id="output" style="width: 300px;"></textarea>
```

---

Или еще проще:

```js
let interval,
    seconds = 0,
    output  = document.getElementById('output');

interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (++seconds < 6)
    output.textContent += 'слово ';
  else
    clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<textarea id="output" style="width: 300px;"></textarea>
```